# Delete Node in XML Structure Java DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom

I'm trying to delete a Node from a XML File parsed with DOM in Java.

```
private Node deleteChildNode (Node node, String nodeName )
{
    Node tempNode = null;
    NodeList nl = node.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++)
    {
        tempNode = nl.item(i);
        if (tempNode.getNodeName().equals(nodeName))
        {                   
            tempNode= node.removeChild(tempNode);                   
        }        
    }
    return node;
}
```

Calling with:

```
nodeClone = deleteChildNode(nodeClone, "L123");
```

But the Node has not been deleted.

```
NodeList nl = nodeClone.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++)
            System.out.println(nl.item(i).getNodeName());
```

Shows the "L123" Node.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would this help? There is a Node and a Name. The Node can be found and is stored in "tempNode" after "node.removeChild". But its not removed in "node". This can not depend on the XML File (because the node was found). And there must be no more Code around it. Just the search for the node to delete.

Comment: I just can't give you more code. I haven't checked out much more from the VersionControlSystem at Friday and it shall work with every xml.

Answer (score 5):

If you have more than one node with the node name under the given node, then your code will not work because you will skip nodes.  using a NodeList while removing nodes is a bit tricky.  basically, when you remove the child node, if modifies the NodeList so that all the following nodes get shifted back one index.  (similar to removing elements from a List while iterating over the list using indexes).  a simple fix would be to add "--i;" after you remove a child node.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's it. And this simple fix works great :D I would like to "vote up".. but my reputation is <15.

Comment: @Skolleus - since you asked the question, you don't vote up, you "accept" the answer.

Comment: @Skolleus - also, in the future, your question would probably have been answered sooner if you had been clear that there were _multiple_ matching nodes and some were getting deleted but not others.

Answer (score 1):

I use this little handy method to clear children of the passed node:

```
public static void clearChildNodes(Node node){
    while(node.hasChildNodes()){
        NodeList nList = node.getChildNodes();
        int index = node.getChildNodes().getLength() - 1;

        Node n = nList.item(index);
        clearChildNodes(n);
        node.removeChild(n);
    }

}
```